# How to get User Details in Laravel Passport

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-passport, laravel-5.6

I am developing an application using Laravel 5.6 and vue.js2. I am using Laravel Passport for User Authentication as API. I am have no `route` about this in `api.php` of Laravel. I have below code in `vue.js`.

```
methods: {
        login() {
            var data = {
                client_id: 2,
                client_secret: 'ispGH4SmkEeV4i5Tz9NoI0RSzid5mciG5ecw011f',
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: this.email,
                password: this.password
            }
            this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token',data)
                .then( response => {
                    this.$auth.setToken(response.body.access_token, response.body.expires_in + Date.now())                        
                    this.$router.push('dashboard')
            })
        }
    }
```

Now I would like to fetch authenticated User details like `userName`,`email` etc.

Answer (score 5):

after you set the token to the header request (which i assume you're doing so in `this.$auth.setToken`), make a get request to `/api/user` route:

```
this.$http.get('/user').then(res => {
     this.user = res.data;
}).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

(this route exists default in the routes/api.php file).